# Bootstrap modal doesn't respond to my PHP submit form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

It doesn't show any error and it doesn't respond when I click Save button. I've tried the PHP insert code in other page without bootstrap and it works I wonder why it's not working in bootstrap modal.

Here's my HTML code:

```
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Add Topic</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cCategory">Category</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cCategory" name="category" value="<?php if (!empty($categ)) { echo $categ; }  ?>">
                          </div>        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cTitle">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cTitle" name="topicTitle" value="<?php if (!empty($topicTitle)) { echo $topicTitle; }  ?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cDesc">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none" name="desc" value="<?php if (!empty($desc)) { echo $desc; }  ?>"> </textarea>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cDesc">Created By</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cDesc" name="createdby" value="<?php if (!empty($created)) { echo $created; }  ?>">
                          </div>
                        </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>

        </div>
```

And this my PHP code:

```
    if(!empty($desc) && !empty($categ) && !empty($topicTitle) && !empty($topicTitle) && !empty($created))   {

        if($insert = $db->query("
             INSERT INTO pncontent (category, title, description, createdby, dateadded)
             VALUES ('$categ', '$topicTitle', '$desc', '$created', NOW() )
            ")) {
                echo $db->affected_rows, " Topic Save!";
            }else {
                echo "Failed to Save";
            }

        }else {
            echo "<p>All Fields are required</p>";
                    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
                    $categ = $_POST['category'];
                    $topicTitle = $_POST['topicTitle'];
                    $created = $_POST['createdby'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button Submit is out of `<form></form>` tag. Kepp it inside `<form></form>` tag to submit the form.

And also check this line:

```
 if(!empty($desc) && !empty($categ) && !empty($topicTitle) && !empty($topicTitle) && !empty($created))
```

Should be:

```
if(!empty($_POST['desc']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['topicTitle']) && !empty($_POST['createdby']))
```

You are checking variables before declaring it, use `$_POST` instead.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php

        if(!empty($_POST['desc']) && !empty($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['topicTitle']) && !empty($_POST['createdby']))   {


        $desc1 = $_POST['desc'];
        $categ1 = $_POST['category'];
        $topicTitle1 = $_POST['topicTitle'];
        $created1 = $_POST['createdby'];

        if($insert = $db->query("
         INSERT INTO pncontent (category, title, description, createdby, dateadded)
         VALUES ('$categ1', '$topicTitle1', '$desc1', '$created1', NOW() )
        ")) {
            echo $db->affected_rows, " Topic Save!";
        }else {
            echo "Failed to Save";
        }

    }else {
        echo "<p>All Fields are required</p>";
                $desc = $_POST['desc'];
                $categ = $_POST['category'];
                $topicTitle = $_POST['topicTitle'];
                $created = $_POST['createdby'];
    }
}
```

Comment: it respond now but it's not showing any error in my condition if textboxes are blank it just refresh.

Comment: and not to force close a modal if i recieved an error

Comment: @NathanielNathan to show errors `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`